# Cannot access certain URL on my wireless

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, dns

**Problem:**

On my wireless network at home, there is one URL that I just cannot access with my browser:

```
http://research.microsoft.com/
```

I have no problems with the Internet connection otherwise. But on that address I just get

```
The connection was reset
The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
```

from Firefox. I am using a DSL modem (Westell) and Linksys wireless router (using DHCP). When I use my neighbor's wireless connection I can access the microsoft site without a problem.

**Additional technical details:**

But with my connection, here is what I get from `nslookup`. It is weird: It first cannot find the address, but after I look up another address it can find it:

```
$ nslookup research.microsoft.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

$ nslookup google.com
Non-authoritative answer:
Name: google.com
Address: 72.14.204.104
Name: google.com
Address: 72.14.204.147
Name: google.com
Address: 72.14.204.99
Name: google.com
Address: 72.14.204.103

$ nslookup research.microsoft.com
Non-authoritative answer:
Name: research.microsoft.com
Address: 131.107.65.14
```

But even after `nslookup` finds it Firefox still cannot access it.

Here is what `traceroute` says:

```
$ traceroute http://research.microsoft.com/
traceroute: Warning: http://research.microsoft.com/ has multiple addresses; using 8.15.7.117
traceroute to http://research.microsoft.com/ (8.15.7.117), 64 hops max, 40 byte packets
 1  dslrouter.westell.com (1XX.XXX.X.X)  4.515 ms  2.760 ms  3.072 ms
 2  * * *
```

Traceroute just to the IP:

```
$ traceroute 131.107.65.14
traceroute to 131.107.65.14 (131.107.65.14), 64 hops max, 40 byte packets

 1  dslrouter.westell.com (1XX.XXX.X.X)  11.912 ms  2.684 ms  2.808 ms
 2  * * *
```

Comparison: Traceroute to google.com IP:

```
$ traceroute 72.14.204.99
traceroute to 72.14.204.99 (72.14.204.99), 64 hops max, 40 byte packets
 1  dslrouter.westell.com (1XX.XXX.X.X)  6.428 ms  6.981 ms  117.099 ms
 2  * * *
```

Any comments / help?

Comment: What IP Subnet did you use for your home network? Would it be 131.107.65.xxx by chance?

Comment: To do an nslookup and traceroute do it without the http:// in front and the / behind.  You only want to use the name.  So something like "nslookup research.microsoft.com"

Comment: would you mind also share the first couple of hops to a website that you can access using traceroute for comparison?  You're westell router appears to definitely not understand where to route your request.

Comment: Also, try a traceroute with just the IP rather than FQDN.  That will help you rule out (or blame) DNS resolution.

Comment: Hmm, no one has an answer ... But it's a mysterious, interesting problem, isn't it? How can something like that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Since you get a Non-authoritative answer from the `nslookup` and the trace won't go any further than your modem, it seems your DNS is being cached. See if your computer, router or modem has DNS caching turned on and if so, turn it off.

Please also try executing the following:

```
nslookup
> research.microsoft.com.
```

Notice the "." at the end of the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure different nameservers such as from [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) or those that result from [namebench](http://code.google.com/p/namebench/).